# getting error with google play services - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-L'

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have recently installed the latest adt. The previous versions were running file with google-play-services.

With the new L release it seems to not work or i am confused.

I tried importing google-play-services - success.
Then i get this error - **"google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-L'"**
      Someone please explain me what it means and how to resolve it ?

Also, i read somewhere that if i create new application with L release it will not have downward compatibility. I want to make clear that i want to use this with lower compatibility as well. How can i do that? Will i need to change some thing in my application code as well?

here is the screenshot of SDK manager.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make API  target of level  19 instead of 20

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem at version 23, I don't know if it's fixed at 23.02 but anyway..
I recommend you to go back to the ADT bundle before the 23v, here is a place you can download from :

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip - Windows 7 64 bit https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321.zip - Windows 7 32 bit https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321.zip - Mac 64 bit

I had the same problem like you, maybe its a problem in the new ADT ..

Comment: no its not the ADT problem. I have resolved this issue by downloading latest ADT as mentioned in Google Post.